# Serving a Tensorflow 2 Keras model with feature columns and preprocessing (migrating from tf 1.x estimators)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

I'm migrating a current Tensorflow 1.x model built with estimators across to Tensorflow 2.0 Keras. The migration has been relatively smooth until it comes to serialising the model for serving.

The model is specified as follows

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns))
for units in hidden_layers:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=None))
```

I am using the Tensorflow feature columns api, which expects as input a dictionary of feature columns, and applying a transformation to those features before they pass into the model.

For example when training

```
def dataset_transformation_function(feature_dict: Dict[str, tf.Tensor]):
    output_dict = feature_dict.copy()
    output_dict['logx1'] = tf.math.log(feature_dict['x1'])
    return output_dict

train_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (train_feature_dict, train_label_vector)
    )
    .shuffle(n_train)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .map(dataset_transformation_function)
    .repeat()
    .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

It appears that to perform the same transformation at serve time I require:

```
input_tensors = [tf.Tensorspec(name=...), ...]
@tf.function(input_signature=input_tensors)
def dataset_transformation_function(args) -> Dict[str, tf.Tensor]:
    ...
```

And

```
tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    MODEL_DIR,
    signatures=feature_transform,
)
```

However I cannot determine the correct signature for the input tensor or the function.

The method I am migrating from is:

```
def serving_input_fn():

    receiver_tensors = {
        'x1': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, ], name='x1')
        'x2': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None, ], name='x2')
    }
    features = dataset_transformation_function(
        receiver_tensors
    )

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

estimator.export_savedmodel(
    MODEL_DIR,
    serving_input_fn,
    as_text=False,
    checkpoint_path=estimator.best_checkpoint,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it seems that the solution is to provide a function which, when called does both the preprocessing and calls the model. Example here:

```
# tensorflow 2.0.0
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

hidden_layers = [4,4]
feature_columns = [fc.numeric_column(name) for name in ['x1', 'x2', 'logx1']]

# construct a simple sequential model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns))
for units in hidden_layers:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=None))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss='mae',
    metrics=['mae']
)

x_train = {'x1': np.arange(10), 'x2': np.arange(10), 'logx1': np.log1p(np.arange(10))}
x_predict = {'x1': np.arange(10), 'x2': np.arange(10)}
y = np.random.random(size=10)

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y)

trained_model_predictions = model.predict(x_train)

# preprocessing function for serving
@tf.function()
def serve_predict(x1, x2):
    preprocessed_feature = tf.math.log1p(x1)
    output = {
        'x1': x1,
        'x2': x2,
        'logx1': preprocessed_feature
    }
    prediction = model(output)
    return prediction

serve_predict = serve_predict.get_concrete_function(x1=tf.TensorSpec([None,]), x2=tf.TensorSpec([None,]))

tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    '/tmp/tf',
    signatures=serve_predict
)
# check the models give the same output
loaded = tf.saved_model.load('/tmp/tf')
loaded_model_predictions = loaded.serve_predict(x1=tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32), x2=tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32))
np.testing.assert_allclose(trained_model_predictions, loaded_model_predictions, atol=1e-6)
```